Modifying the RDB as a publisher and memory issues
The following is a modified version of the RDB r.q. I have given the RDB the ability to publish its results which I would like to then post-process in a q subscriber. In the background I have the 'vanilla' tick.q running. First of all, is this efficient, for I haven't seen any examples with r.q having .u.pub? If not, what's the recommended approach?
The memory usage of the q process running the RDB suddenly jumps from a baseline 1.5GB to 38.5GB at which point the process often crashes. The baseline RAM usage is consistent with the size of the data in the tick.q log file, but the latter value is both puzzling and concerning. I also see warnings in r.q run like 'snd handle: 9. OS reports: Broken pipe. I'm not entirely sure what's causing this behaviour. A possible reason is that my subscriber is 'slow' but I've examined the time per iteration therein and that's about 100ms --well below the timeout here of 1000ms.
/q tick/r.q [host]:port[:usr:pwd] [host]:port[:usr:pwd]
/2008.09.09 .k ->.q

\l tick/u.q
\l tick/sym.q

if[not "w"=first string .z.o;system "sleep 1"];

upd:insert;

/ get the ticker plant and history ports, defaults are 5010,5012
.u.x:.z.x,(count .z.x)_(":5010";":5012");

/ end of day: save, clear, hdb reload
.u.end:{t:tables`.;t@:where `g=attr each t@\:`sym;.Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym];@[;`sym;`g#] each t;};

/ init schema and sync up from log file;cd to hdb(so client save can run)
.u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;if[null first y;:()];-11!y;system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y};
/ HARDCODE \cd if other than logdir/db

/ connect to ticker plant for (schema;(logcount;log))
.u.rep .(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)";

/ modified section
.u.init[]

.z.ts:{.u.pub[`quote;quote]};
\t 1000

\p 5011


Is this script for your RDB or TP? It looks like a script you'd write for a TP publishing on a timer.

I understand, but It's definitely my RDB, and it's the standard r.q with some modification at the end. Per my understanding the TP holds only a small amount of quotes. I'd like to post process all of them, hence the need to post-process them after the RDB.

Aren't you publishing the entire (growing) quote table every 1000ms on the timer? Your RDB is storing every quote, aka upd:insert and then you're publishing the entire quote table downstream? (.u.pub[`quote;quote]) Why doesn't the RDB do the calc and publish the result of the calc? Don't re-publish the entire quote table every time

Thanks @terrylynch, I figured out later that that’s the issue as well.
